# Use repl instead of println in Clojure

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

Let's say we need evaluate a number of clauses in a source file, e.g.

test.clj

```clj
@(def x 1)
@(def y 2)
@(def z 3)
```

Only the last evaluation shows up if we plainly use either `clj` or `lein repl`,

```
user => (load-file "test.clj")
3
```

We can surround each of them by `println` to show all of them,

test-with-println.clj

```clj
(println @(def x 1))
(println @(def y 2))
(println @(def z 3))
```

```
user => (load-file "test-with-println.clj")
1
2
3
nil
```

What are the better alternatives to avoid invasive `println`s all over the source code while able to print out all the intended evaluations under the umbrella of REPLs?

**@Solution**

Thanks to `tap>` from the answer @Sean Corfield we can have desired results as follows,

- pipe every wannabe printed out to `tap>`.

test-with-tap.clj

```clj
(-> @(def x 1) tap>)
(-> @(def y 2) tap>)
(-> @(def z 3) tap>)
```

- REPLs will receive none of their outputs until `tap>` is turned on by `add-tap`.

```
user=> (load-file "test-with-tap.clj")
nil
user=> (add-tap @(def out (bound-fn* println)))
nil
user=> (load-file "test-with-tap.clj")
1
2
3
user=> (remove-tap out)
nil
user=> (load-file "test-with-tap.clj")
nil
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tap>` is probably what you're looking for - https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tap%3E - This lets you send full Clojure values (not just strings) to any function registered as a listener, which can be something like Portal for example - https://github.com/djblue/portal - which is something I use all-day, every-day, but you can also use something as simple as `println` in `add-tap` to get every `tap>`'d value displayed.

The `tap>` calls can stay in your code, even in production, since there is next to no overhead to using them.

Although `tap>` returns a Boolean, you can use `(doto expr tap>)` to evaluate and return `expr` but still send the value to any tap listeners. `tap>` is a great debugging tool.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Sean. What `tap>` offers is surprisingly even better than that I could have conceived at very beginning.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't had a chance to play with `tap>` yet.  My favorite over the years has been the `spy` family of functions [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging).  Specifically, check out `spyx`, `spyx-pretty`, and [let-spy](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.11.06a/api/tupelo.core#let-spy).

Comment: Alan, Thanks a lot for your well maintained wonderful project. I'll definitely add it to the toolkit.